# Checking if my webservice doing anything?

Tags: c#, web-services

I have asmx webservice and I need to check , if webservice is busy.

I'll ask about it from my winforms client .

Comment: What do you mean by "busy", your web service should be able to handle many concurrent requests.

Comment: I mean he doing some request from other clients

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A way to achieve this would be to write some registry key value like:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Phenevo\WebService\<ThreadID>
```

..when your ASMX is entered, and remove the value when you're done. The WinForms code can simply count the number of values underneath the '..WebService' key - if there are more than 0, it's busy.

Unfortunately, it is not possible to have a static variable that you increment and decrement due to worker processes getting recycled.